# cisco switch fan deaulty temp defaulty

Tags: cisco

I have a stack of cisco 3750 switch (c3750-48ps) which has 4 switches total. Out of 4 one of the switch is showing fan faulty and temperature faulty. I checked the switch and found out that the speed of the fan of that switch is higher than the speed of the fan of the other switches. How can i trouble shoot this or fix this?

Comment: I don't think there is a way of changing the RPM on the fan's. They are controlled by what the current ambient temperature is, and adjust RPM as needed. Some fan trays might have jumpers that allows you to switch between ambient temp control and full speed. To me it sounds like you have a fault and might want to look at RMA'ing the faulty switch.

Comment: Got it. Thats what i am thinking of too. Also, I am planning on a reboot just to make sure if the alert goes away by doing so, if not then i will be RMA'in it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *environment* command as a starting point:

> show env all

The first part of the output should be similar to:

```
FAN 1 is OK
FAN 2 is OK
FAN PS-1 is OK
FAN PS-2 is OK
SYSTEM TEMPERATURE is OK
System Temperature Value: 29 Degree Celsius
System Temperature State: GREEN
Yellow Threshold : 46 Degree Celsius
Red Threshold    : 60 Degree Celsius
```

In this example both chassis fans and both power supply fans are reporting all's normal.  The system temp is good and I have 17 degrees to go before I reach *temp warning.*

If one fan is hosed it is very likely that system temp increased and the remaining variable-speed fan has picked up the pace to keep the switch cool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The above case is for the switch (3750x) with the separate fan module that can be easily removed and replaced. In my case the switch (3750) have built-in internal fan. And when i apply the commands, this is what i get;

SWSTACK#sh env all
FAN is OK
TEMPERATURE is OK
Temperature Value: 42 Degree Celsius
Temperature State: GREEN
Yellow Threshold : 58 Degree Celsius
Red Threshold    : 68 Degree Celsius

This is the switch in the stack having faulty fan
SWSTACK#sh env stack 4
SWITCH: 4
FAN is FAULTY
TEMPERATURE is FAULTY
POWER is OK
RPS is AVAILABLE